# How can I get my web cam to work in Adobe Connect?

Tags: webcam, adobe-connect

Enjoying the [90 free-day access in Adobe Connect](https://www.adobe.com/products/adobeconnect.html), I downloaded the product for my W10 machine, created a new meeting and connected in the Windows app.

Once trying to see the output of my camera, it shows the following grey screen.

[Grey camera in Adobe Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rHyn.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried updating the drivers for the webcam? It could also be possible that your webcam is outputting a better quality than Adobe connect can handle, then recommended settings for Adobe connect is 640*480 @ 20 fps, so I would try adjusting the webcam settings to that to see if that makes a difference